# lookup funtion in datagridview

Tags: datagridview, vlookup, lookup

I'm creating a project in Visual Studio 2017 using Visual Studio language, and I'm linking datagridview with an external .xls file. The problem is that I want to extract values from the datagridview table automatically without selecting any row and any column. In other words, I'm looking for a lookup or Vlookup function that seeks the value wanted, linking the labels associated to such a textbox with the texts in the table once I download it in the datagridview, and then copies the right value from the cell to the right textbox.

Please Could you help me ? I'm really blocked !!!

Comment: Visual Studio is not a language. What have you tried?

Comment: So you have your `DataGridView` filled with the XLS file, right? How did you do that, is it connected as datatable? You should provide a code you have at the moment. And what exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you make an example what `Cell` value to what `TextBox` you want to fill?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are trying to get the value on "A2" (first row, second column), you can use this in C#:

```
var a = myDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value;
```